# How to copy lines that contain match by findstr

Tags: findstr

I have a file (source.txt) which contains such lines, for example:

```
123 sdf asdfa 342 ololo
asdf ololo sdf sdfa s3
asdf asf ad 34234 1klj
asdf 2342 fgasd34 dlll
ololo sdfsfd asdf342 323
```

And I want to copy all lines that contain "ololo" to another file (result.txt), so that result.txt file will contain the following  lines (the 1st, the 2nd and the 5th):

```
123 sdf asdfa 342 ololo
asdf ololo sdf sdfa s3
ololo sdfsfd asdf342 323
```

How could I do this? I write the following command:

```
findstr "ololo" D:\source.txt >D:\result.txt
```

but in the result.txt file I get the following output:

```
ololo
ololo2
ololo3
```

How can I copy all line with match to result file?

Answer (score 0):

strfind will just find where your required string present, problem with that is when a string is subset of any word it takes comeplete work.

Use the command find(strcmp(ololo, {source.txt})) or strcmpi(not a case sensitive). you will get exact positions where ololo is present in your cell.